Integral of exponential of 2-norm
I am in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Given fixed $k \in \mathbb{R}$ and parameters $v \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $s \in [0, \infty)$, I want to obtain
$$\int_{[-k, k]^d} \exp\left(\|v - e^{-s}x\|_2^2\right){\rm d}x$$
in closed form as a function of $v, s$. I imagine that it would be easier to first compute
$$\int_{[-k, k]} \exp\left(\|a - e^{-s}x\|_2^2\right){\rm d}x$$
with $a \in \mathbb{R}$, but I'm having more trouble than I'd expect.
For the $d$ dimensional integral, I've tried building up
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_{[-k, k]^d} \|x\|_2^2{\rm d}x\\
&\int_{[-k, k]^d} \exp\left(\|x\|_2^2\right){\rm d}x\\
&\int_{[-k, k]^d} \exp\left(\|e^{-s}x\|_2^2\right){\rm d}x\\
&\int_{[-k, k]^d} \exp\left(\|v - e^{-s}x\|_2^2\right){\rm d}x\\
\end{align}
$$
But I get stuck even by the second integral. My end goal would be to resolve the second integral, splitting the norm in the fourth into norms and an inner product term. The exp norm of $v$ term is fine, but I'm having troubling handling the exp inner product and exp norm of $x$ terms. Any help is welcome
This is not homework, but pointers or suggested that help me figure it out are preferred to just solving the integral for me.

What do you mean when $a$ is a scalar? What is the answer when $d=1$?

@TedShifrin I get $2e^{a + s} \sinh(ke^{-s})$

Offhand that seems unlikely to me. I don't expect there to be a reasonable answer, certainly, when $d>1$.

You are correct @TedShifrin, I dropped the square. I now get $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}e^s(\text{erfi}(a+ke^{-s}) - \text{erfi}(a-ke^{-s}))$. Onto producing bounds I guess...
